# What is CLASS:wxWindowNR in AutoIt, and how can I click the control?

Tags: autoit

I'm using AutoIt to try to automate the use of a program called PhotoZoom 4. I'm running into a problem where I need to type text into a box where this is the Class and instance:
[CLASS:wxWindowNR; INSTANCE:8]

I've tried the following with no luck (each line is a separate attempt):

```
ControlSetText($batchWindowTitle2, "", "[CLASS:wxWindowNR; INSTANCE:8]", '800')

ControlCommand($batchWindowTitle2, "", "[CLASS:wxWindowNR; INSTANCE:8]", "AddString", '800')

ControlClick($batchWindowTitle2, "", "[CLASS:wxWindowNR; INSTANCE:8]", "left", 1, 32, 12)
Send("800")
```

I expected either ControlCommand or ControlSetText to work at least, but they didn't.
I googled this problem as well, but I literally couldn't find any references of "wxWindowNR" anywhere on the web. I'll attach a photo of the control.

If you don't know what wxWindowNR is either (I expect you might not since I have not seen it anywhere else on the web), what's the best way to automate clicking and typing in the box? I thought ControlClick would do it...

[image: The control I'm working with]

Comment: Did you try to "Tab-cycle" (e.g. `send("{Tab 5}")`) through all your controls until you get there in your GUI and then use a simple `send()`?
Your GUI is probably preventing automation and checks for actual HW states whether your mouse or keyboard is actually pressed. This would be hard to manipulate.
And does [`GUICtrlSetState(..., $GUI_FOCUS)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlSetState.htm) work? You need to `#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>`.

Comment: Excellent, the Tab trick worked! Sometimes you gotta think more simply like that..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tab-cycle" (for example, `send("{Tab 5}")`) through all your controls until you get there in your GUI and then use a simple `send()`.